# How to produce a highly accurate phase or frequency shift at 500 MHz?

Tags: rf, test

I currently have a couple of function generators that can be tied together in order to produce an arbitrary frequency or phase shift up to 20 MHz. Essentially I could say I want FN Generator 1 to be pi/8 ahead of FN generator 2. Or I want FN1 to be 19.99 MHz and FN2 to be 20 MHz.

Is there any easy way to do this at 500 MHz? I have been able to find function generators that can go up to that speed, but have yet to find one that can have an arbitrary shift from another signal.

So does anyone actually make function generators that do what I want? If not, is there a way that I could generator these type of signals myself? Ideal voltage out would be 0 to 5v and sin or square wave is acceptable.

Comment: While this is a quite interesting question in its own right, I'd be curious to hear about the application for which it is useful.

Comment: @chris it is for a project that I am working on that requires some proof of concepts to be proven. Long term the freq and phase difference would come from a saw sensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are vector phase shifter/modulator devices on the market.  Basically, you generate a fixed shift (ideally around 90 degrees, but not critical) and then proportionally add/substract the original and fixed-shift phases to produce any desired output phase.

Getting best performance (especially if the fixed shift is not 90 degrees) would require using DACs to generate the control voltages for each phase from a lookup table based on measurements previously taken at a particular frequency (or automatically over a range of frequencies, perhaps using a GPIB-connected vector network analyzer)

RE-EDIT: Since you have a solution at low frequencies, one option is to just mix each of these up to 500 MHz using the same local oscillator and pass the outputs through matched band filters.  This is slightly more practical if you use arbitrary generators capable of outputting a higher frequency, say 100 MHz, as then the filter requirements are looser.  Ultimately this is sort of reshuffling of the same idea - it's still multiplication, but your control inputs are moderate frequencies instead of DC voltages and it moves the shifting requirement through the multiplier to where it is easy, at the cost of requiring some filters on the other side.  And there's even a form where you replace the filters with a quadrature (2-phase) local oscillator and image reject mixers.

ADDITIONAL IDEA:

A pair of lower frequency linked generators could be used as references for PLL synthesizers multiplying to the desired frequency range.  Changing the phase of the low frequency signal will result in a phase change of the high frequency one, of magnitude multiplied by the multiplication factor (think of the phase change as a time delay, with which the higher frequency signal must also align).  The catch is that extremely fine control of phase would be necessary at the low frequency to get moderate resolution control at the higher one.  For example, if you have a 20 MHz signal synthesized at 100 MSPS, a delay of one sample is 5 entire periods of a 500 MHz product!   As a result, this would require a DDS with many bits of residual phase - that is to say, less significant bits of the phase accumulator that accumulate internally, and only eventually roll over into the bits that are of a high enough order to feed into the lookup table that generates sine samples.  Any decent DDS has some of these; in this case you'd need an extreme.  The idea probably works best when the DDS frequency is as high as practical - ie a few hundred MHz clocked at a gigasample (which is something you've been able to buy as an IC from Analog Devices etc for a few years now) and the PLL multiplication ratio is fairly low.

Most of these ideas seek to use a greater quantity of relatively inexpensive (per unit) active circuitry and even software to limit the requirement of expensive per-unit-adjusted precision passive elements.  Unfortunately, most require pairs of filters or a shift network with performance that is either similar, or been per-unit characterized so that its imperfections can pre-compensated in the control settings used.  The method using two low frequency DDS's and image reject mixers goes closest to avoiding this, but it needs near perfectly orthogonal quadrature LOs at fixed frequencies for each band - for example 400 MHz to mix to the 500 MHz band.  It may be possible to create two phases by digitally dividing from a higher frequency, otherwise there would be a shift element that would need to be aligned for each band of interest.  The soundcard-as-HF-exciter ham software-defined-radio people have done some looking at precompensating the synthesized signals to compensate for imperfect IQ LOs and mixers which could be looked into, but since the idea is to have perfect cancellation of the image frequency (vs filter it out) this is pretty critical.

**Simple answer if $$ available**

If budget permits, Agilent and presumably others offer dual channel and synchronizable arbitrary waveform generators that will do 500 MHz either directly or via an IQ mixer.  As an off the shelf solution, this would be closest to extending what you are able to do at 20 MHz to the 550 MHz need.  Such equipment is rented as if not more often than purchased outright.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could add a adjustable R-C filter to the function generator output to create a signal with lagging phase.  This would have to be amplified to match the original signal, since phase shift and attenuation in this case go together.  Or conversely, you could attenuate the original signal before using it so that it matches the amplitude of the delayed signal.

Also, at 500 MHz it doesn't take much of a cable to phase shift by delay.  500 MHz means 2ns/cycle, which should be between a foot or two of decent transmission line.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If you (whoever you are) think there is something wrong, misleading, or didn't like the way I said something you really should say so.  As it is now, nobody knows what you disagree with and I have no idea what I would have needed to do to avoid the downvote.  Downvoting without explanation is just drive-by vandalism.

Comment: It appeared to have been over-rated by others, as while this would be the start of a solution it's not clear how you would make this both arbitrary and highly accurate as the question requests.  A workable solution would use one of these methods to accomplish the shift, but would likely require substantial mechanical complexity, manual or feedback adjustment each time the shift was changed, or most likely a precomputed digital combination of many fixed shift blocks or an analog proportionate summation of 2 or more shifted phases to achieve the desired net shift at a given frequency.

Comment: @Chris: Two votes is hardly being overrated.  Also, the OP never said anything about required accuracy or ease of adjustment, or if the amplitudes of the signals mattered at all.  Note that he even said square waves would be acceptable.  It seems you are imposing your own requirements beyond what was actually asked about.  As far as I can tell, the ideas I mentioned would fit his requirements *to the extent he has stated them*.

Comment: I guess that depends on what the "highly accurate" and "arbitrary shift" appearing in the question and title mean to you.

Comment: @Chris: "Highly accurate" without actual numbers means nothing, of course.  We also don't know if this accuracy needs to be achieved directly from some input from the user, or via feedback by looking at a scope, for example, to adjust things until the desired phase shift is accomplished.  Again, you are adding your own assumptions and biases to the OPs question.  I gave some ideas for what he asked.  They may not be what he wants, but then that's a fault of his spec.

Comment: He seems to be drawing comparison to programmable function generators with his examples of commanding phase or frequency, so you can imply quite a bit from that.  Phase is a harder problem, and it does come down to what you are willing to pay for.

Comment: @Chris: It seems the real problem with my suggestions are that they don't fit the narrow One Right Way you decided is right.  You haven't given any reaons a slider along a delay line wouldn't work fine and even be quite "accurate", whatever that means.  Personally I reserve downvotes for blatantly stupid, misleading, or just plain wrong answers, but I guess everyone has their own criteria.  I also don't around downvoting without comment, but that's just me apparently.

Comment: you've failed to specify how you would calibrate a slider - as I allowed, this could be done but would be "mechanically complex" to integrate into a system.  The downvote was really more a reflection on those who upvoted an *incomplete contribution* than a rejection of that contribution - indeed, my own suggestion depends on a mechanism perhaps such as you proposed to produce its component fixed shift(s), but focuses on achieving an accurate and arbitrarily adjustable result therefrom, without placing undue requirements on skilled user adjustment hence its more common use for arbitrary shifts.

Comment: @Olin you can't expect every op to know all of the details that are needed to be given to get a proper answer. If you think there is more detail needed then ask for more in a comment. I have seen you get very mad at people before for not giving enough detail. I am glad you are helping contribute, but I would rather not be here if you are just going to be rude to people who don't know better.

Comment: I assumed my comparison of a function generator would provide an idea of what I was looking for, primarily being easy to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Googling ...

If it's readily available commercially then [Minicircuits](http://www.minicircuits.com/homepage/homepage.html) hav a good chance of being a source for it [and these Minicircuits products sound like a start](http://www.minicircuits.com/products/phase_shifters.shtml).

This looks like what you want - [Ferroelectric field conrolled phase shifter](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=1122376)  (2003) but I don't know it it has been commercialised.

Pasternak. [Product line](http://www.pasternack.com/category-Phase-Shifters-11.html), [Datasheet for DC-2GHz](http://www.pasternack.com/Pdf/PE8243.pdf). Maximum phase shift 60° per GHz, or 30° at 500 MHz.

Comment: Those devices from Minicircuits look very nice (and cheap). I wish they would provide more details, such as the pin-out of the IC.

Comment: @Kellenjb I've certainly seen plenty of mini-circuits data sheets, and recall getting them from their web site, but it does appear to be somewhat broken at the moment.  I was able to find a random one: http://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/JSPHS-150.pdf - note from the shift vs frequency and control voltage plot that it will require something like a a DAC driven by an interpolated calibration table to achieve "highly accurate" shift

Comment: "Seem to have a knob on one end..." - I just had to click the link.  You're right.  The only information I can add about those devices is that they seem to come in the color blue, and run about $600-1800, depending on your frequency range.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer - if you click on the PDF view tab for the DC-2GHz unit you get an engineering drawing with a data block stating a range of 60 degrees per GHz and a half dB insertion loss.  That implies only 30 degrees of shift available at 500 MHz.

Comment: @Chris - Ah, missed that.  Added updated links to the answer.